# Sort List<string> like Excel columns sort

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, c#-4.0

Please consider this List:

```
"A", "C", "AB", "AD", "N", "Z", "AC"
```

I want to sort this string (That are being Excel column) like Excel Column Sorting.

I want the result like this:

```
"A", "C", "N", "Z", "AB", "AC", "AD"
```

Is it possible using LINQ OrderBy?

What is the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: If I were in your place I would have tried to sum the ascii code of the chars available and then sort it. For example A = 65, C = 67, ... AB = 65 + 66 = 131 and so on.

Comment: Just to note: This order is called [quasi-lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Quasi-lexicographic_order).

Comment: If you target .NET 4.5 (2012) or later, even if you tag this C# 4.0, and if you want to `Sort` the `List<>` in-place, you could use something like `yourStringList.Sort(Comparer<string>.Create((x, y) => { var c = x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length); if (c != 0) { return c; } return x.CompareTo(y); }));`. If the list may contain `null` values, you need to take care of that in the lambda of course.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava But that would make `"AB"` and `"BA"` equal.

Comment: Absolutely Right @JeppeStigNielsen. `.OrderBy(p=>p.Length).ThenBy(p=>p);` is the best way to do so. :)

Comment: @Joey That link also uses, among others, the name *shortlex order*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen for correct comment, I add `StringComparer.Ordinal` to support in all cultures:

```
var result = List.OrderBy(p=>p.Length).ThenBy(p=>p,StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Comment: I thought a bit about it. That should be `.ThenBy(p=>p, StringComparer.Ordinal)` in the end. Otherwise it will depend on the current culture in a complex way. For example with _Lithuanian (Lithuania)_ `"lt-LT"` you would have `"Y"` before `"R"` (the letter Y is collated between I and J in Lithuanian). Another example, in _Czech (Czech Republic)_ `"cs-CZ"` we get `"DI"` before `"CH"` since CH is a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(digraph)#Czech) in Czech and comes after H in its collation. Test for yourself with `StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("lt-LT"), false)` etc.

Answer (score 3):

First order by the length of column name ("C" comes before "AB"), then use normal alphabetical (string) sorting on strings with same length ("AC" before "AD").

```
var columns = new[] { "A", "C", "AB", "AD", "N", "Z", "AC" };
var sorted = columns.OrderBy(c => c.Length)
                    .ThenBy(c => c);
```